# Install custom program with no user interaction

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to create a program that can install a program that user select (user select installer from disk). I know how to run a executable file using Process class.
But how to install a program without user interaction (silent install)?

Comment: Are you using a particular installer, such as Installshield, or Windows Installer (MSI), or are you writing the installer code yourself?

Comment: I would like to install any program that user selects.
Example:
User download "programName_installer.exe" and select that exe from my program and hit install. Now i would like to perform silent install from code.

Answer (score 1):

Your installers you plan to run, need to support silent installs.  If they don't, you're going to have a difficult time

Luckily, most installers allow the same command line arguments as an MSI.  Try running your installer as `programName_installer.exe /?` and see if it give you a help popup.

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/msiexec.mspx?mfr=true) is a list of MSI command line options.  `\qn` removes all UI interaction for it.

In addition when you run your process, you need to have these settings to make sure no console popup appears to the user:

```
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("programName_installer.exe", @"\qn");
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.RedirectStandardError = 
                info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            using (Process process = Process.Start(info))
            {
                process.WaitForExit();

                string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

                string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

                int exitCode = process.ExitCode;
            }
```